# Adding org.apache.kafka to dependencies with Gradle

Tags: gradle, apache-kafka, log4j

I started a Gradle project with `gradle init --type java-application` using Kotlin as the build script DSL, and I just wanted to add `org.apache.kafka` library

```
dependencies {
    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre")

    implementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.0")

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
}
```

But `gradle build` returned this:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find jmxtools.jar (com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:1.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/jdmk/jmxtools/1.2.1/jmxtools-1.2.1.jar
   > Could not find jmxri.jar (com.sun.jmx:jmxri:1.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/jmx/jmxri/1.2.1/jmxri-1.2.1.jar
```

What's this about? Conflicts with JCenter?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Kafka?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I solved it using 2.12 version 2.3.1

Comment: You should also be using kafka-clients if you just want producer/consumer

Comment: This problem was caused by log4j (see answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments upgrading the kafka version will solve the problem (probs go to @cricket_007).

The root cause for that problem is actually not kafka itself but it's transitive dependency log4j in a version 1.2.15. This log4j version requires jmxtools and jmxri. Due to some licensing issues these artifacts are NOT available on maven central and jcenter. The good news is: You most likely don't need it at all. You simply override the log4j dependency to use 1.2.16 (or above) or exclude jmxtools and jmxri.

You can also find some more insights in this blog article: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/18/resolving-log4j-1215-dependency-problems-in-maven-using-exclusions/

So 3 ways to solve this issue:

- use a more recent kafka-version **OR**
- use a log4j version > 1.2.15 **OR**
- exclude jmxtools and jmxri

Hope that helps and make things more clear